# How to (hide) NOT show £0.00 in Price sets for the FREE options?

Tags: price-sets

I have a price sets, which have an option FREE. How to NOT show £0.00 in Price sets for the FREE options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you tuck in your FREE options into a separate Price Field? And then to not show any $ values for all options within a given Price Field: de-select the display amount checkbox:

[image]

Comment: Glad I could help out!